# How to dynamically create and use a derived class from a base class?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I want to use a pointer to a parent class to allocate and use a child class object. I have an Animal class with a child Dog class, the Assign class should add a Dog class to its Animal pointer array (`Animal**animals`). At the moment `cout<<animals[0]->weight` outputs correctly, but `animals[0]->breed` gives error:  `Class 'Animal' has no member named 'breed'`. I have to do it like this as this is for a practical (this is also a simplified example, as in the real example we'll have an array of Animal/derived Animal objects). Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Animal{
public:
  double weight;
  Animal(double w){
    weight=w;
  }
  void shout(){
    cout<<"Weight: "<<weight<<endl;
  }
};

class Dog: public Animal{
public:
  string breed;
  Dog(string b,double w): Animal(w){
    breed=b;
    weight=w;
  }
};

class Asign{
public:
  Animal**animals;
  Asign(){
    animals=new Animal*[2];
    animals[0]=new Dog("Great Dane",12.2);
    cout<<animals[0]->breed<<endl;//Does not work
  }
};

int main(){
  Dog Duke("Great dane",12.2);
  Asign a;
}
```

Comment: Is every `Animal` supposed to be have a `breed`? If so, then class `Animal` should have  a `breed` member. If not, then `animals[0]->breed` is not sensible since not every `Animal` has a `breed` so there is no way to get a `breed` from an `Animal`. Heck, who even knows what type it is? `Cat` could be derived from `Animal` and have an `int` called `breed` for all the compiler knows.

Answer (score 0):

An `Animal` (the base class) does not have a `breed` member variable, as a result you are receiving the error. Even though a `Dog` has a breed member variable, the `Animal` knows nothing about it. The correct code would be to cast the `Animal` pointer to a `Dog` using a `dynamic_cast` to cast down the class hierarchy, then you will have access to the class member:

```
cout<<dynamic_cast<Dog*>(animals[0])->breed<<endl;
```

Note in general its good practice to check if the pointer returned by the `dynamic_cast` is not `NULL` before using it, as it can return `NULL` if the cast failed.

Comment: When using `dynamic_cast`, make sure to check the return value for NULL before using the pointer, eg: `Dog *d = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(animals[0]); if (d) { cout << d->breed << endl; } else { /* not a Dog, do something else */ }`

Comment: Casting from `Animal` to `Dog` would be downcast, not upcast, right?